# How do I create a list of items so you can dynamically update [DOJO]

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a global json variable that is setted from a function.
A EdgeToEdgeStoreList create the list one time and don't update it when the variable change.

How force the refresh of the displayed list?

With this :

```
storeOrdiniCliente.data=new_data;
```

I update the data (and it works) but not changed the displayed list!

How do I create a Dojo list of items so you can dynamically update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the programmatic creation of a EdgeToEdgeStoreList

```
<ul id="ulElencoOrdiniClienti"></ul>
```

and

```
var sampleStore = new Memory({data:ordini_cliente_data, idProperty:"label"});
storeOrdiniCliente = new EdgeToEdgeStoreList({store:sampleStore}, "ulElencoOrdiniClienti");
storeOrdiniCliente.startup();
```

it's  need to execute this statement, after the update of the var listini_clienti_data

```
storeElencoListiniClienti.generateList(listini_cliente_data);
```

Comment: If this is in fact an answer to your own question, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.